# RUBY: How do I subtract each element from left to right and return the max difference?

Tags: arrays, ruby, data-structures, iteration

I'm so sorry for the basic question. Studied coding for a month now and I still blank out at data structure questions.

```
array = [6,2,3,7]
```

6 cannot be subtracted with something

2 - 6 = -4

3 - 2 = 1

7 - 3 = 4

so 4 is the max difference

Comment: Why can't `6` be subtracted from `2`? What should the result be for `array = [11, 7, 4, 2, 1]`? What should the result be for `[]`? And for `[1]`?

Comment: I see! There wasn't any particular reason for it to be non-negative. Idk why I placed it like that. I'm going to edit it

Comment: In an array of **n** elements, you have **(n-1)** differences (correspondings to the "gaps" between the elements. I would simply loop from the second element to the last one, and calculate the difference to the respective previous element. You may want to consider whether you really mean the **difference** here or the **distance** (i.e. the absolute value of the difference).

Answer (score 4):

The Ruby-way is to use [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons), which @Joel has done in his answer. I will present an alternative approach.

---

Let's create a method `max_consecutive_diff` that takes a single argument, an array of integers.

```
def max_consecutive_diff(arr)
  ...
end
```

---

We might start by dealing with the case where the array `arr` is empty or contains a single integer. It appears from your example that the method should only be called when `arr` contains at least two elements. You therefore way want to check that at the beginning and raised an exception if `arr` contains zero or one element.

```
def max_consecutive_diff(arr)
  raise(ArgumentError, "arr contains fewer than two elements") if arr.size < 2
  ...
end
```

---

In the following I will use the array

```
arr = [6,2,3,7]
```

for illustration.

---

We first need to compute an array of element differences. Suppose we begin by computing an array of the indices of all but the first element of `array`: `[1,2,3]`. Then we can use [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-map) to map those indices to the associated differences:

```
indices = [1,2,3]
diffs = indices.map { |i| arr[i]-arr[i-1] }
  #=> [-4, 1, 4]
```

There are various ways to compute `indices`. Here is one, that uses the class method [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-c-new):

```
indices = Array.new(array.size-1) { |i| i+1 }
   #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

---

Another way is to compute a *range* of indices<sup>1</sup>:

```
indices = 1..arr.size-1
  #=> 1..3
```

and then write

```
diffs = indices.map { |i| arr[i]-arr[i-1] }
  #=> [-4, 1, 4]
```

This does not use, `Array#map`, as `map`'s receiver is a range, not an array. Instead, Ruby sees that this is [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)). `Enumerable` is a module and not a class. As

```
Range.included_modules 
  #=> [Enumerable, Kernel]
```

we see that the class `Range` has included the module `Enumerable`, so it has access to all of its instance methods. In time you will learn the details of how this works and why it is so useful.

Note that storage requirements are reduced by using a range instead of an array. I believe that most Rubyists would use a range here.

---

Regardless of how `diffs` is computed, the final step is to compute its largest value, using [Array#max](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-max):

```
diffs.max
  #=> 4
```

---

Our method now becomes

```
def max_consecutive_diff(arr)
  raise(ArgumentError, "arr contains fewer than two elements") if arr.size < 2
  indices = 1..arr.size-1
  diffs = indices.map { |i| arr[i]-arr[i-1] }
  return diffs.max
end
```

---

We can simplify this by substituting out the variables `indices` and `diffs`, and removing the keyword `return`.<sup>2</sup> We can do the latter because when `return` is not present Ruby will return the result of the last calculation made by the method.

```
def max_consecutive_diff(arr)
  raise(ArgumentError, "arr contains fewer than two elements") if arr.size < 2
  (1..arr.size-1).map { |i| arr[i]-arr[i-1] }.max
end
```

It's entirely up to you to decide whether to make these simplifications. That is, it's a question of programming style.

---

Let's try it.

```
max_consecutive_diff([])
  #=> ArgumentError: arr contains fewer than two elements
max_consecutive_diff([1])
  #=> ArgumentError: arr contains fewer than two elements
max_consecutive_diff([1,'cat'])
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "cat":String
max_consecutive_diff([1,2])
  #=> 1
max_consecutive_diff([2,1])
  #=> -1
max_consecutive_diff([1,2,4])
  #=> 2
max_consecutive_diff([1,2,5,4,6])
  #=> 3
```

<sup>1. Many--possibly most--Rubyists would write this with a three-dot range, which excludes the right end-point: `indices = 1...arr.size`. As a rule I avoid the use of three-dot ranges because I believe having two types of ranges results in coding errors that can be difficult to locate. I say "as a rule" because three-dot ranges are sometimes needed when defining ranges of floats.</sup>

<sup>2. Note that `(1..arr.size-1).map { |i| arr[i]-arr[i-1] }.max` could be changed to `(0..arr.size-1).each_cons(2).map { |i, j| arr[j]-arr[i] }.max`, which can be further simplified to `arr.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| b-a }.max`.</sup>

Comment: I guess the only additional question is what "max difference" means e.g. is it distance from 0 or numerical max.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I was going by the last two lines of the question. I expect you, like I, are closely following world events, but you have greater reason to be disturbed by them.

Comment: Nice walk-through, maybe replace `(1..arr.size-1)` by `(1...arr.size)`. And if you refactor a little further you'll eventually get `(0...arr.size).each_cons(2).map { |i, j| arr[j]-arr[i] }.max` and ultimately `arr.each_cons(2).map { |i, j| j-i }.max` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
array.each_cons(2).map { |a,b| b - a }.max
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons

Comment: Did you mean `each_cons`?

Comment: Both work actually! each_slice.to_a did the same thing. but I concede yours is nicer

Comment: `each_slice` doesn't work. Consider `[1,2,7,7]`. `each_slice` compares `2-1` with `7-7`, but `7-2 #=> 5` is the answer. Also, if `array.size` is odd, an exception will be raised, as the last element `a` the enumerator `array.each(2)` passes to the block will be an array having have just one element, so `a[1] #=> nil`.

Comment: Considering the OP is new to Ruby I suggest you provide an explanation.

Comment: The OP showed that for his/her example, `3-2` is one of the differences to be considered. `each_slice(2)` would not consider that pair.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes you are correct - OP wants consecutive pairs.

Comment: Or, if you want the pair with maximum difference: `array.each_cons(2).max_by { |a, b| b - a }` which returns `[3, 7]`